# lag happened while using fabric.js in vue3

Tags: vuejs3, fabricjs

we would like to create a electronic whiteboard project by using fabric.js,

the project is almost done, but still has a little problem,

it would be lagged after we write about 200 times on our pdf handout,

is there anyone having related experience?

[this is how our electronic white board looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajo21.png)

```
 // we doubted that the problem comes from here
```

this.canvas.add(pathObj)

```
  const state = this.canvas.toJSON(['eventInfo'])
  const action = {
    type: 'draw',
    data: null
  }
  this.state = this.getState(state, action)
  this.saveHistory(this.state)
```